# adapter.addAll(collection) is destroying the order of objects on list

Tags: android

In an already poluplated ListView's adapter when we add more data using adapter.addAll(Collection) it looks like it is adding elements in random order. Is that truly the case if so what is the way to add more data in ordely manner:

```
 ArrayAdapter<GroupPostValues> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<GroupPostValues>) listView.getAdapter();

adapter.addAll(moreData);
```

Comment: try to add single data using iterate moreData.

Comment: addAll is always add all data at end of list please read this funcation description here :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: You should write your custom adapter, where you can write your custom logic into addAll method to sort added items.